# What exactly is the "Oily Black Stone", and why is it everywhere?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *The World of Ice and Fire* (TWOIAF), a companion book to the *A Song of Ice and Fire* series, there are [repeated references](http://asearchoficeandfire.com/?q=black%20stone&scope%5B%5D=twoiaf) to  mysterious "black stone" (often described as oily or greasy), which composes, among other things:

- The Seastone Chair
- Yeen
- The Toad on the Isle of Toads
- The Five Forts of Yi Ti
- Hightower's foundations
- Asshai

What exactly is the significance of this black stone? Is it related to dragonglass? Why is it found in such diverse locations?  Have Elio, Linda, or GRRM (the authors of TWOIAF) said anything regarding it?

Comment: It's petrified dragon poo.

Comment: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Black_stone

Comment: Is there any mention of or allusion to this in any of the novels?

Comment: @user568458Yes, but not much.  Mainly in discussion of the Seastone Chair

Comment: @user568458 http://asearchoficeandfire.com/?q=black+stone&scope%5B%5D=agot&scope%5B%5D=adwd&scope%5B%5D=acok&scope%5B%5D=asos&scope%5B%5D=affc

Comment: I would guess it comes from Valyria, some way or somehow.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister it's suggested that this stone is *not* from Valyria, but from an earlier race of beings called the [Deep Ones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Deep_Ones)

Comment: Out of universe, I’m pretty sure it’s another callback (along with the Drowned God and Deep Ones, among other things) to the Lovecraft Mythos. Note also a giant toad creature associated with it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Stone

Comment: Out of universe,  tar? It's oily and is stone like

Answer (score 4):

Well according the [ASOIAF wiki entry on "black stone,"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Black_stone) it is used in many supernatural instances.

For example, Maester Theron theorizes that the black stone was produced by the [Deep Ones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Deep_Ones) - "[a] queer, misshapen race of half men sired by creatures of the salt seas upon human women."

Meanwhile, "The Bloodstone Emperor rejected the traditional gods of Yi Ti and instead encouraged the worship of a black stone said to have fallen from the sky."

Based upon what I found, I would venture to guess that it does not have anything to do with "dragonglass."  As to why it is found in such "diverse locations," it may just be a coincidence or it may have something to do with the aforementioned supernatural elements present in the series.